# Question Regarding a Class of Students

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A class has less than 30 students.

1. Exactly 3/4 of them own footballs.
2. Exactly 7/8 of them own football boots.

   i.How many students are there in the class?

   ii.How many students own both football boots and footballs?

Comment: There is not enough information: the number could be any of $8$, $16$, or $24$.

Answer (score 2):

Take the number of students as $x<30$ and take $y$ as the number of students with both football and football boots, then form your equations

- $\cfrac 34 x$ own footballs
- $\cfrac 78x$ own football boots
- $\cfrac 34x + \cfrac 78x -y = x \iff 5x-8y=0 $

Solve the last equation for non negative integer values of $x$ and $y$ less than $30$